# How to apply credentials in VBA to refresh extracted data from SQL Server on Excel?

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, refresh, credentials

I have an Excel file where it is connected to multiple tables from an SQL Server. This is how I connected it

[image: This is how I connected it].

All the tables are loaded fine on the sheet, however these tables are a reference to specific actions on Excel so they need to be up to date on Excel itself. The sheet is going to be used by multiple users, so I have set a macro that when they press a button all tables gets refreshed in their Excel files so the data is always up to date.

It works perfectly for me as I have a username and password for the database, however these users don't have a username and password. Once they click the button to refresh the data, they get a pop up to enter the database credentials.

[image: Once they click the button to refresh the data, they get a pop up to enter the database credentials].

What I am trying to do is apply my own credentials in the VBA code of that button, so once they click the refresh button, all tables in excel gets refreshed and excel doesn't ask the user for credentials.

If anyone has a way of doing it, please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of sql server do you have and could you please add your code to your question, tha would be helpful.

Comment: Whatever your code is, probably you'll need to check this: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/ to find the appropiate string to connect to your database with your username and password. Please, note that username and password will be coded, so anyone with acces to code will be able to get them.

Comment: I am not really sure about the coding of such things, that why i didnt add any code to my question. however, I tried couple of codes i saw online but nothing worked for me. On the excel sheet in the properties of the data source table it shows that the connection type is "OLE DB Query". I am hoping if someone could help me with the coding for my issue. Thanks for your replies